# Group By in conjunction with combining groups?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Looking for some help on how to Group By in conjunction with combining the grouped by items. Any chance someone would be able to help here?

Example below: Multiple transactions in the same state with transaction amounts. I want to group transactions A+B together, but keep C transactions separate.

Data:

```
Transaction Type, State, Amount
A, SC, 43.00
B, SC, 44.00
C, SC, 45.00
B, SC, 46.00
```

What I want the output to look like is:

```
A+B, SC, 133.00
C, SC, 45.00
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: What tells us what Transactions to group together? Is it hardset that A and B go together? Is there some other underlying logic?

Comment: I'm actually doing this under M$ Access, so would that be Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: @MPelletier - Yes, sorry - here is the overall logic: These are databases of tax transactions. What I am trying to separate out is tax transactions. One tax transaction type we want to be coded separate, while the rest we want to be associated/grouped together.

Comment: MS Access is a DBMS. SQL Server is another DBMS. Different things.

Comment: And what tells us that tax A goes with tax B? Is it something in another column or not?

Comment: Nothing - it's just a matter of grouping for summarization (Ex: Grouping Sales Tax with Use Tax [A+B], and leaving out Rental Tax [C]). Sorry, hope that helps.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN [Transaction Type] IN ('A','B') 
        THEN 'A+B'
    ELSE [Transaction Type] 
    END [Transaction Type],
State,
SUM(Amount) Total
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN [Transaction Type] IN ('A','B') 
            THEN 'A+B'
        ELSE [Transaction Type] 
    END, 
    State
```

?

Comment: MS Access is giving Syntax Error (Missing Operator) and highlighting the WHEN  of the Select Statement.